# "Brigand Attack" (when upgrading Settlement --> City)

Tags: struggle-for-catan

I just bought this game last week and had a question (and BGG couldn't help...)

When read at face value, it would seem that

> "Each player who has more than 7 resources must discard all excess resources"

would require discarding *down to seven cards* when this event occurs. The [official rules (.pdf)](http://www.catan.com/en/download/?SfC_Rules_042511.pdf) don't really say anything to enforce (or refute) this.

But having played **Settlers**, I wonder if the intent is to discard *half* (rounding down)...

**How should this be treated?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The card is poorly worded. It should probably say, "Each player who has more than 7 resources must discard all resources in excess of 7."

At the [Official Catan Game Portal](http://www.playcatan.com/cow-instructions/struggle-for-catan.html):

> Brigand Attack: Players who have more than 7 resources cards discard all cards in excess of 7. Afterwards, the destiny card is flipped.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was very close to finding that link, but must have clicked "rules" instead of "learn game" (or something like that)!